# Flexbox not displaying on Safari 5.1 for Windows

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to create a simple box for a question, with the question number on one side and the text on the other. As the texts are dynamic and I want them to be vertically aligned, I'm trying the use of flexbox.

[image: Desired effect]

I've read about the [old and new syntax](http://css-tricks.com/using-flexbox/) and I've tried to cover all the possible scenarios (if that is ever possible) with the necessary prefixes, for example:

```
  display: -webkit-box;
  /* OLD - iOS 6-, Safari 3.1-6 */
  display: -moz-box;
  /* OLD - Firefox 19- (buggy but mostly works) */
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  /* TWEENER - IE 10 */
  display: -webkit-flex;
  /* NEW - Chrome */
  display: flex;
  /* NEW, Spec - Opera 12.1, Firefox 20+ */
```

Here's a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/alkaithil/NW3QZ/5/

However, **I can't see the box displayed at all in Safari for Windows** (5.1).

Any ideas or alternatives for this kind of layout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We must understand the actual use of the `flex`.

In this situation you have to use `display:table-cell` with `.question-text p, .question-text span`

**Remember BEST use of `flex` is for Column Re-Ordering**

For your solution, Please go through this code as well as [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/NW3QZ/8/)

```
html,
body {
margin: 0 auto;
padding: 0;
}
body {
background: #222;
font-family: 'HelveticaNeueThin', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
font-size: 62.5%;
position: relative;
}
.slide-wrapper {
text-align: center;
}

.boxed {
background: #314353;
border-color: #1c89e8;
color: #e8e8e8;
border-radius: 0 20px 20px 0;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 1px;
display: inline-block;
font-size: 2.2em;
margin:0px;
}

.question-text {
color: #1c89e8;

margin: 2em auto 0 auto;
max-width: 80%;
text-align: left;
}

.question-text:before,
.question-text:after {
content: "";
display: table;
}
.question-text:after {
clear: both;
}
.question-text p,
.question-text span {
vertical-align:middle;
display:table-cell;
padding: 0.5em;
}

.question-text span {
background: #1c89e8;
color: #FFF;
border-top-left-radius: 20px;
border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
font-size: 4em;
}
```

Comment: with `display: table-cell` as you suggested the layout seems to work  just as I wanted, thanks! anyway, could you point me to some reference about flexbox best uses? I've read a bit about flexbox but haven't realised it was specific for column reordering.

Comment: @ithil, sure i'll provide you some demo, which showing the use of flex, as per my research uptill now its mostly use for column re-ordering, but there are some other uses too of flexbox